# Downvoting my correct answer - Who or Why?

Tags: discussion, support, downvote-reason

My answer is correct (completely confident about that) and I am the first one to answer. Even then someone downvoted my answer. Someone added a comment below my answer that is exactly the summary of my answer. Can I find out who is downvoting or why?

Comment: No, but you can't, and this is done for a reason, just the same as why you can't see who or why up-votes your questions or answers.

Comment: It could be because that the voter believes that your answer is not useful, or [Tim losing his keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/288751), or they may not have liked your approach, or they might just dislike your avatar. You can never (and will never) be able to find out who or why someone downvoted your post. The closest you can get would be if that person chose of their own accord to leave a comment.

Comment: @TinyGiant - Exactly, there could be a thousand things that might have been wrong. A downvote without proper comment is not always useful

Comment: As an aside, I've seen plenty of people "completely confident" about their answers whilst still being very wrong. I'm not saying that's the case here, but confidence in correctness isn't the same as correctness itself.

Comment: @Vinod Downvotes are always useful information. It means that one person thinks that the question or answer is in some way not useful, my previous statement is only to say that if no comment is left and you cannot possibly see any problem with your post then move on, you cannot squeeze water from a stone.

Comment: @TinyGiant - I never said that they aren't useful. And I am only talking about answers here, if you down-vote an answer, atleast leave a comment. I always do that, it helps the people understand what is wrong with their post

Comment: One reason for downvoting an answer without commenting: there may already be a comment saying exactly what your comment would.

Comment: I'm confused -- none of your [three](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34130944) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34013694) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33997608) have a single down vote...

Comment: @JonSkeet - Yes, that is completely fine. As long as there is atleast one comment :P. I've seen you leaving comments when you DV. It really helps us improve

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar: Yes, I usually do. Not always, but usually - and when I don't, it's usually because there's already an explanatory comment, which I upvote at the same time.

Comment: @JonSkeet - That's how we know what's wrong with our answers. I do the same

Comment: Who should be irrelevant but why (even at a somewhat broad level) is really something a legit user should understand if we want the site to improve in quality at a faster pace. There are definitely a lot of lazy/illegitimate users who are beyond hope and might ideally just be banned, but helping the legit ones like the op here who are earnest about editing and improving shouldn't just be left in the dark with a mystery down-vote. This shouldn't ever happen -- at least some anonymous clue/hint should be provided. If we want to promote quality, we can't just punish without stating a reason.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, you can't find out who downvoted. Stop worrying about downvotes. The bank won't repossess your house if you get too many downvotes. Your children won't starve because of downvotes. The milk in your fridge might go sour faster, but probably not; anyway, sour milk ain't that bad.

...Now that you're not worrying about downvotes, use all your new-found free time to review your answer and look for areas where you might improve it. Are you in any way unclear? Misleading? Could you perhaps explain your solution in more detail? Consider folks who communicate using a different flavor of English; might they find your answer hard to parse? Read any comments carefully: these are the reflections of those who've read your answer... What do they say about the mindset of those readers?

Once you've made your answer *as good as it can possibly be*, then - if there are still downvotes in evidence - enjoy a good hearty laugh at those confused voters, and treat yourself to a nice cup of hot tea.

Comment: HOT TEA? YOU MONSTER I'LL DOWNVOTE THIS (or not).

Comment: In other words: *Try improve your answer better and better. And then, no need to be afraid of downvotes*.

Comment: I still see a big flaw in how SO treats downvotes.  Downvotes are useless unless accompanied by atleast one comment. Most people don't mention what is wrong with an answer and leave the *figuring out* part to the poster. Well, if you have time to downvote, you should have time to say what's wrong

Comment: @Vinod: Downvotes unaccompanied by a comment can safely be assumed to mean: "*This answer is not useful*" or "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.*"

Comment: @TinyGiant- *"This answer is not useful"* , is actually **too-broad** in itself. Tell the poster what is wrong

Comment: @Vinod What if I don't think that the post could possibly be improved, and it is just plain wrong, and I don't feel like being accosted by user angry at being downvoted?

Comment: @TinyGiant - That's the risk we will have to take. Ignore what the user says about the *reason for downvoting*. Just leave a comment. I've seen people downvoting my answers sometimes. The fact that I might be wrong scares me. Look at the question here, the OP doesn;t know why her posts were downvoted

Comment: @Vinod I spend most of my day looking at garbage content so that others may possibly benefit from my work cleaning that content up. I don't think it is feasible to comment on every post I downvote, let alone justifiable. I don't want to start a discussion about every vote I cast, I just want to cast my votes. If I think a discussion about the votes I cast is warranted, I will start one.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar I'm quite prepared to add comments on all my downvotes, and I don't much care about any 'retaliation'.  What I don't get is how I'm going to get paid for the time spent doing it?

Comment: "The bank won't repossess your house if you get too many downvotes." With Greek banks, I wouldn't be so sure... /sigh

Comment: I've already cut down my 'free' download comments, eg. 'debugger.........DCV' when a poster has not made any effort to debug.  Shorter/quicker comments would be more misleading than no comments.

Comment: @MartinJames - Would you rather do one thing right or 5 things *partially-right*?

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar I would prefer to do nothing at all, but still have people give me money.  Unfortunately...........

Comment: @MartinJames - I can settle for gold or platinum :P

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar I agree, but I like the idea of just choosing a reason to down-vote among a template, just like we do for close votes. With Tiny here, he's looking at OT questions all day which probably have the person raising the question being clueless. But not all people who get down-voted are beyond hope -- and it'd be nice if they can anonymously know why. Even just something like, *"This answer is not detailed enough/incorrect/poorly-worded/doesn't address the question."*  Anything -- one extra click goes from a ??? to something, and something is infinitely better than nothing.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar The way I see it is that this will help the legit users (not the ones beyond hope) improve their skills faster, and that can help the entire site as a whole by increasing the numbers of users who provide quality questions and answers. For the hopeless people we down-vote, all we need is one extra click.

Comment: @Ike - I agree, it would probably make sense to have a DV reason. That way atleast the OP might know what's wrong with his / her post. Frankly I am only concerned about trying to help who deserve an explanation. I am not talking about spamsters and *give-me-the-codez* posts

Comment: "Stop worrying about downvotes. The bank won't repossess your house if you get too many downvotes. " Yes, bank won't repossess my house if you get too many downvotes. But it will blocked me answering questions and answers,

Comment: I have seen people downvoting correct accepted answers because the question was *too easy* and it encourages asking *stupid*? questions

Answer (score -3):

Quit answering. If you are a volunteer and not a troll I think they should even tolerate a mistake every now and then.