# Downvotes for correct answers is offensive

Tags: support, downvotes

I found [an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311915/downvoting-my-correct-answer-who-or-why), but it is not solving my issue.

I agree with the answer' on the above question that nothing will happen even if I get downvoted. But we are here at Stack Overflow to help others as well as improve ourselves.

Getting downvotes continuously for correct answers is very disturbing.

**I can't get food for upvotes, I agree.**

But I repeat it is somewhat offensive.

Is Stack Overflow planning to do something to handle such people?

For example, *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42485381/enabling-a-button-on-validating-input-fields/42485497#42485497*.

For example, *[copying an input from a text box to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42484625/copying-an-input-from-one-text-box-to-another/42485015#42485015)*

Comment: here also downvoting. asking question is a house-breaking offence??

Comment: Downvoting here means something different that on SO. It means "I don't agree with what you wrote"

Comment: downvoting in meta is just disagreement. Does not impact your rep in any way as far as I know

Comment: @suraj I am not caring about rep. you did somewhat good job to someone for free and they said very bad opinion about it. What did you feel? i feel the same. Thats what i said. Don't misunderstand me

Comment: I'm curious, why are not you finding upvotes offensive, in general?

Comment: no issue.. the idea behind it is to have the best answer on top for people looking for a solution. If either your solution is not ideal or is missing explanation it may get down voted as some of the answers said

Comment: @Tunaki I vote use my votes carefully. If an answer is working, then only i upvote. and i am very cautious about downvotes

Comment: You didn't answer the question.

Comment: Also.. people cant downvoted willynilly as they lose a point for every downvote (unless the answer gets deleted) and there are other measures for malicious downvotes

Comment: @SagarV: please *downvote more*. Bad content doesn't get enough downvotes. Please vote on the *usefulness of an answer*, which is much broader than just correctness. An answer that only dumps code without explaining what the code does may technically be correct, but is *not useful*. And stop taking offense at downvotes, or if you must, then be consistent and take offense at unexpected upvotes for unhelpful posts too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree. but one question __downvote more__ . people atleast make an effort to answer. It may fail in some case. if so, the down voters should atleast let him know this is the reason for downvote. Then it will make him understand `I made a fault` and he will correct it in future. But without letting him know why the downvote will make him feel bad. That is the reason I downvote rarely because they atleast made an attempt where many people didn't

Comment: Better not to post anything, than post something not useful. Don't vote because _hey the poor user tried to help!_. That's focusing on the user, while you should focus on the content.

Comment: Making an attempt, while maybe nice; is actually worse for the site than making no attempt at all if the post is not useful enough for the community at large.

Comment: Paradoxically, **not** commenting on a downvote [sometimes works better](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265769/812149). When you comment, the poster often gets defensive. When you don't comment on  a downvote, they can only look into their own heart for a reason. Before commenting on a downvote, consider if the user will take your comment to heart - or just get angry.

Comment: [How can we discourage over-downvoting on questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253230/476) *cough cough*

Comment: re "Then it will make him understand I made a fault and he will correct it in future." Or not, after 15 times repeating to someone to include explanation with his/her code dump, you can give up on trying to say it yet another time to yet someone else who didn't read the help.

Comment: @CodeCaster I still vote on content whoever it is, from time to time (once a week) I scan my rep tab for -1 to check if it worth removing the vote. There's some people (FGITW) I gave up upon, and I refrain to vote on their answers that said.

Comment: @SagarV: take into account we do give new posters a lot of help in figuring out what SO is about and what is expected of questions. They have *already* been given information about what makes a good question. With the volume of questions we see every day, it is very noble to want to leave feedback with every vote but that's not always possible. And even with a comment, some people still see downvotes as some kind of attack on their person, but now they have someone to direct their anger at: the person that commented. So there is a scaling issue, and a need to avoid confrontations.

Comment: Also.... you need to calibrate your "offensive"-meter.... offensive is really strong for what is here just disagreement with a vote.

Answer (score 31):

First of all, don't take offense in downvotes. It's just someone expressing their opinion on what you wrote, they're not downvoting you as a person.

So you should not post this Meta question seeking retaliation (*"Is SO planning to do something to handle such people?"*), but you should instead search your own heart: are you definitely sure that there's nothing wrong with these answers?

I can't speak for the downvoter, but for your first answer, you're suggesting a particular regular expression to validate names (see: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)) and another one to validate email addresses ([Validate email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript), read the comments). So while the idea is OK, the implementation is not. This is definitely worth downvoting.

Then the second answer, I can't vouch for the implementation, but at a glance it seems correct. The answer itself however is a mere code dump without explanation, which again, is downvoteable: the answer is not clear.

Altogether though, you must realise that you're answering very low-effort questions (they're definitely duplicates) in the highest-traffic tag on the site. You are bound to get some flak for that if your answers aren't entirely perfect, and frankly, such questions should not be answered but closed instead.

That being said: an answerer by themself is generally not in the position of evaluating whether their answer is one that contains a correct, fast and secure solution that helps not only the asker but also future visitors.

Sure, the code in the answer may work for the one test case you tried, but maybe someone more experienced than you sees ten ways in which it will fail. They're not required to explain their downvote, leaving you confused. That's never going to change unless you gain more experience and then look back at your earlier answers, realise what you did wrong and improve your future answers with that knowledge.

Or, in short, and no offense intended: if you're answering to the best of your abilities and still get downvoted but don't understand why, then try to improve your abilities before answering more.

Comment: the OP is noob for validation and putting complex regex is very difficult for him otherwise he will make an effort to learn regex

Comment: @SagarV one thing you have to realize though is you aren't answering the question for the OP.  You are answering for everyone who has the same problem and finds your answer in the future.  If you put a simplified answer down for the OP's benefit, you are not providing a good answer for anyone else in the future.

Comment: @SagarV Providing an incorrect answer that the question author can understand is still an incorrect answer.  If they're not in a position to actually understand a good solution to their problem then that doesn't mean it's fine to give them a poor solution to their problem *and claim that it's a good solution*.  That's not how they'll learn and get better, that's simply a way to cause grief for them as they find all of the flaws with the answer.  Knowing that they don't know how to solve the problem is better than getting a bad answer without even realizing it's a bad answer.

Comment: but it is not just for them. It is for future visitors too

Comment: @SagarV there is zero benefit for future visitors when the question is badly written/badly titled/the 1,000,000th duplicate of a question already thoroughly answered on the Internet. Stack Overflow is not a one-on-one help forum. One-on-one help rarely benefits future visitors.

Comment: (For what it's worth, I know you mean well. But a place like this needs standards and some strictness to survive and function.)

Answer (score 8):

Well your first answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42485381/enabling-a-button-on-validating-input-fields/42485497#42485497

Your first draft only included a minimal answer, that you then edited with the sample. SO that might explain the down vote?!

Your second answer:

[copying an input from a text box to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42484625/copying-an-input-from-one-text-box-to-another/42485015#42485015)

Simply contains a code sample, that might be correct, but you've not put any effort in to explain your answer, which might explain the down vote. I dislike it when people simply post code to answer a question.

If you're going to post a code answer, put some effort in to explain the code you've posted and why it works. Makes answers like that far more useful.

Aside from all this, don't worry about down votes here and there. If your answers are good, they will get more votes over time. If you do get down votes, think for a second about why someone may have voted and see if you can improve your answer.

Comment: ok. fine. but it is still there even after I updated the answer. It might make future visitors is not a correct answer and keep scrolling. It will not help anyone. I given the minimal answer first because the OP didnot put any effort on it. In second question we can assume that he is a noob and if we start to describe, it takes more time to make him understand. Thats why so.

Comment: In addition: Both questions are bad question in the style of "give me teh codez plz" questions. It is not wanted on SO to answer such questions because they don't have any value to the community. But if they get answers such questions tend to be asked again. That's why a lot of people also downvote answers to such questions.

Comment: @SagarV Then write a complete answer first **and** don't answer incomplete questions. The goal is to build a quality repository of Q/A, not to answer every question.

Comment: *but it is still there even after I updated the answer* @SagarV - You can't expect people who have voted on your post to come back and vote again after you've edited it. They have no idea you've made any changes and may have no reason to ever come back to the question.

Answer (score 8):

Both of those questions should realistically be closed as 1. too broad and 2. unclear what you're asking. They're essentially "Plz give me teh codez" questions without any attempt at solving them, which leaves any answers to just be guesses. The second one doesn't even contain an actual question.

A lot of people downvote answers when they believe the question should not be answered at all. The downvote button says "This answer is not helpful" and if people believe that it isn't they can/should downvote it. There is no reason why something should be done about these people.